# JQuery validation rule wih C# code

Tags: c#, jquery, validation

i have some sequential `input` fields in a html form and want to apply some validations, So i tried a `C#` for loop inside the validation and stucked around !
my code is

```
for (var i = 1; i <= 7;i++)
       { 
        <text>
                    @("input" + i): {        // <--error
                        required: {
                            depends: function () {
                                return $('@("#option" + i)').val() == 'somevalue';
                            }
                        },
                    },
        </text>
       }
```

Its showing some error at first line.
Any help will be appreciated, Thank you

Comment: What does the error _say_?

Comment: You should use a Javascript loop; it will be _much_ easier to write & debug.

Comment: @SLaks  "expected identifier string or number" and if i try "@("input" + i)" then no error but its taken as a string, So validation dosen't work.

Comment: @SLaks how can i insert a javascript loop inside form validation ?

Comment: Use a regular Javascript loop to build the parameter object, creating a property in each iteration.